# Restarting a GStreamer pipeline after X minutes has passed

Tags: multithreading, gstreamer, video-recording

I have a written a working GStreamer application to record an RTSP stream into a .avi file. The general pipeline is as follows:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=... ! decodebin ! x264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=video.avi`

What I would like to do now is to record a new video file after every X minutes. For example, running the GStreamer application for an hour will give me 12 video files of 5 minutes each instead of 1 video file that is 60 minutes long. I thought of a few ways to do it:

> 1. Create a timer thread to that sleeps for 5 minutes and then send an EOS signal, following with relevant re-initialization.

I'm not sure if this is actually possible because I don't think the timer thread is able to communicate with the bus.

> 2. Create an external thread to run the GStreamer section and restart the thread every 5 minutes.

I'm not sure of the side effects from this method. Terminating a recording pipeline abruptly appears to corrupt the timings of the video clock e.g. a 10 second video initially appears as 13 seconds in length.

> 3. Make use of whatever GStreamer has that is keeping track of the time in `GST_STATE_PLAYING` and send EOS to the bus after 5 minutes.

I'm not sure how to do this but I think this combined with method 2 is the best way to do it.

> 4. Using `num-buffers=(X*60)*fps`

This makes sense going by the math but the framerate has to be known before using it as a multiplier.

How do I go about implementing method 3? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If you're restarting your pipeline and missing a second or two of data does that matter?  The possible solutions vary quite a bit based on that.

Comment: @mpr Better something than nothing :) It'll be a good start for me (and others) to experiment with so please share some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the multifilesink plugin for gstreamer?
If yes then you can use the property max-duration for splitting file at regular intervals 
After a bit search is see that this property is in nanoseconds. 
Thus your command can be something like for 1 seconds split

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc multifilesink location=video%04.avi max-duration=1000000000 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! avimux ! filesink

Comment: It appears that `max-duration` in the multifilesink element does not exist. Upon further research, it is only available as a [patch](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/commit/?id=27c91bc881704a7ec1d5f64bca8f2862463bdbd7). What version of GStreamer are you working on? I am on 1.2.4 because I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I am using gstreamer 0.10 actually. But i build my plugins from source since these are for embedded platform.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a timeout and restarting the entire stream with a new filesink location would be the simplest solution.  Just add a timer (you can use glib if you like):

https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add-seconds

Grab the bus and post EOS:

```
GstBus* bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(my_pipeline));

gst_bus_post(bus, gst_message_new_eos(GST_OBJECT(some_object)));

gst_object_unref(bus);
```

If you're storing something important though, you probably want to make sure there is overlap on the files.  In that case I might suggest having an outside process (say a shell script) generate the file name and call your program with some overlap.

You could also do something fancier with the `output-selector` element, where you have your starting pipeline like this:

`rtspsrc0 -> decodebin0 -> output-selector0 pad-negotiation-mode=active -> (x264enc0 -> avimux0 -> filesink0)`

...then you go to this:

```
rtspsrc0 -> decodebin0 -> output-selector0 -> (x264enc0 -> avimux0 -> filesink0)

output-selector0-> (x264enc1 -> avimux1 -> filesink1)
```

...and change the active-pad from `src_0' to`src_1`, send EOS to the first set of AVI elements, leaving you with this:

`rtspsrc0 -> decodebin0 -> output-selector0 pad-negotiation-mode=active -> (x264enc1 -> avimux1 -> filesink1)`

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-output-selector.html